# Why does this indirect call (call rax) take >100 cycles average?

Tags: performance, assembly, profiling, x86-64

Edit: this question was a mistake.  I misread the time spent in the subroutine and thought the statement in this routine was taking 15% of the overall time instead of the actual 3%.

I leave the question here because of the high quality of the answers.  I am surprised that the computed branch seems to miss even though the destination is always the same address and I will use the suggestions there to investigate.

Original:

This is the key point in my C code, with the annotations from the profiler.  The indirect call takes a third of the overall time of a few-hundred-line loop.  Based on the overall run time this call statement must be taking at least 100 clock cycles.

[image: A profiling run]

Here is the generated code for the last 3 C statements:

```
00007FFE066FB5EA  mov         r12,qword ptr [r8+8]  
00007FFE066FB5EE  and         r12d,30000h  
00007FFE066FB5F5  dec         r12  
00007FFE066FB5F8  and         r12,qword ptr [r8+20h]  
00007FFE066FB5FC  sar         r12,3Fh  
00007FFE066FB600  and         r12,qword ptr [r8+10h]  
00007FFE066FB604  lea         rbx,[validitymask+60h (07FFE06B058E0h)]  
00007FFE066FB60B  cmove       r12,rbx  
       A *tpopa=AZAPLOC(arg1); tpopa=(A*)((I)tpopa&REPSGN(AC(arg1)&((AFLAG(arg1)&(AFVIRTUAL|AFUNINCORPABLE))-1))); tpopa=tpopa?tpopa:ZAPLOC0; tpopw=(pline&2)?tpopw:tpopa; // monad: w fs  dyad: a w   if monad, change to w w  
00007FFE066FB60F  mov         rsi,qword ptr [rdx+8]  
00007FFE066FB613  and         esi,30000h  
00007FFE066FB619  dec         rsi  
00007FFE066FB61C  and         rsi,qword ptr [rdx+20h]  
00007FFE066FB620  sar         rsi,3Fh  
00007FFE066FB624  and         rsi,qword ptr [rdx+10h]  
00007FFE066FB628  cmove       rsi,rbx  
00007FFE066FB62C  test        r15b,2  
00007FFE066FB630  cmove       r12,rsi  
       y=(*actionfn)((J)((I)jt+(REPSGN(SGNIF(pt0ecam,VJTFLGOK1X+(pline>>1)))&(pline|1))),arg1,arg2,fs);   // set bit 0, and bit 1 if dyadic, if inplacing allowed by the verb
00007FFE066FB634  mov         bl,28h  
00007FFE066FB636  sub         bl,cl  
00007FFE066FB638  shlx        rcx,rdi,rbx  
00007FFE066FB63D  sar         rcx,3Fh  
00007FFE066FB641  or          r15d,1  
00007FFE066FB645  and         ecx,r15d  
00007FFE066FB648  add         rcx,r10  
00007FFE066FB64B  vzeroupper  
00007FFE066FB64E  call        rax
```

As you can see, there is nothing exotic about the offending statement, except for the **call rax**.  I expect that call to create a pipeline break of maybe 15 clocks, but nothing like what I am seeing.  In fact, this code is executed in a loop and most of the time the function address is the same, so I would expect that most of the indirect calls would predict properly.  But that's sure not what I am seeing.

The instruction that loads the branch address (which is in the first C statement shown) is executed long before the branch address is used; that is, the address is settled.

Why is this statement/instruction so slow?

Second question: when does the statement end for profiling purposes?  If the **call rax** requires a pipeline break, do all interrupts occurring during that break count against the call rax?  That would make sense, but other instructions are still executing then, right?

Comment: Where does the function pointer in RAX come from?  If it's from a cache-miss load, then that's normal.  An instruction reading a slow-to-produce result gets the blame for it, the way perf counter hardware is designed for counting events like "cycles".  (I'm not sure how the cost of frequent branch mispredicts would show up, but yeah that should be ~15 cycles per call at worst).  Also not sure how I-cache misses in the target function would show up, but probably as counts for the code address that missed.

Comment: You can use x86 hardware counters to see if it is a code cache-miss or a data cache-miss. However, you need to take several samples to get interesting results and you should take care the context is the same (eg. not to make the cache hot while it could be cold in the actual use-case). On Linux perf can do that. On Windows, Vtune for example can do it too.

Comment: Shouldn't you expect subroutine/function calls to take a lot of time? You throw your IP into them and then sit around until it comes back out.

Comment: What profiler is this, and what settings is it using?  I think @MikeDunlavey has a good point that this might be reporting not just the time taken by the `call` instruction itself, but also by the entire execution of the subroutine which it calls.

Comment: You don't have much evidence of a branch miss.  It could be any number of things; if I had to guess, I'd say it's most likely an occasional data-cache miss loading the function pointer, stopping the `call` from actually *retiring* sometimes, but not stopping speculative execution into the correctly-predicted target.  Use `perf record -e branch-misses,L1-dcache-load-misses,cycles` / `perf report` to investigate.